# Sql Server, Select count of users at a location on any given day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables:

Table A:

```
[Location]    [TotalUsers] 
LocationA     5
LocationB     10
LocationC     6
```

TableB:

```
[User]        [FromLocation] [ToLocation] [StartDate] [EndDate] 
UserA         LocationA      LocationB    01/01/2013  05/05/2013
UserB         LocationB      LocationC    02/02/2013  04/04/2013
```

I also have a calendar table which may help.

What I want to do is for each date in the calendar table query Table B to give me a count of how many users are each site on any given day. Alos using the overall user count in Table A I could have a totoal for every day.

Ideally the resultant dataset would be in the format of:

```
[Date]           [LocationA]  [LocationB]  [LocationC]
01/01/2012       5            10           4
```

Or

```
[Date]           [Location]  [UserCount]
01/01/2012       LocationA    10
01/01/2012       LocationB    10
01/01/2012       LocationC    10
```

I can provide more detail if required.

Comment: What do the `FromLocation` and `ToLocation` represent? Do both contribute towards the count of users at a particular location, or only one? (E.g. only `ToLocation` matters?) Some sample data and expected results would help (please include multiple locations and users in the sample).

Comment: If you can provide us the table structure, then, it will be easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TableA

```
LOCATION    TOTAL_USERS
LOCATION_A  5
LOCATION_B  10
LOCATION_C  6
```

TableB

```
USER    FROM_LOCATION   TO_LOCATION START_DATE  END_DATE
User_A  LOCATION_A  LOCATION_B  2013-01-01  2013-05-05 
User_B  LOCATION_B  LOCATION_C  2013-02-02  2013-04-04
```

Query

```
DECLARE @DATE_TO_QUERY datetime = '01/01/2013'


SELECT 
    DATE_TO_QUERY, LOCATION_A, LOCATION_B, LOCATION_C
FROM (

SELECT 
    A.TOTAL_USERS,
    @DATE_TO_QUERY AS DATE_TO_QUERY,
    A.LOCATION
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.LOCATION = B.FROM_LOCATION
OR A.LOCATION = B.TO_LOCATION
WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, START_DATE, @DATE_TO_QUERY) >= 0
AND DATEDIFF(DD, @DATE_TO_QUERY, END_DATE) >= 0

) up
PIVOT (SUM(TOTAL_USERS) FOR  LOCATION IN (LOCATION_A, LOCATION_B, LOCATION_C)) AS pvt
```

Result from above query

```
DATE_TO_QUERY LOCATION_A    LOCATION_B  LOCATION_C
2013-01-01     5              10             NULL
```